# How are null values handled in Spark 2.0 when creating a DataFrame? Is there a way to use Option?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a DataFrame from an RDD in Apache Spark 2.0

```
val spark = new SparkSession()
val fieldList = List(
      StructField("name",StringType,true),
      StructField("age",IntegerType,true),
      StructField("number",LongType,true)
    )

    val schema = StructType(fieldList)

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(Row(Some("Jesus"),22,123456789),Row(Some("Peter"),30,45678912),Row(None,18,127834783))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)

df.write.parquet("/Users/dummy")
```

The exception thrown is the following

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:537)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:363)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Some is not a valid external type for schema of string
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:276)
```

The problem here is that for an unknown reason the dataframe is not accepting the values of class Option. I don't understand why since in Spark 1.6 i was able to create a dataframe using Option values. I'm trying to force the use of Option here because i don't want to use null values.
Is there any way the dataFrame can accept Option values in Spark 2.0 .